# How do I inherit documentation inside an extended class in JsDoc?

Tags: jsdoc3

Probably asking this wrong. Without copying the params from Foo to Bar, how do I inherit documentation of an extended class in JsDoc? When I run jsdoc from the command line, I would like to see Bar get Foos documentation (esp for the constructor).

**Foo**

```
/**
 * This is Foo.
 *
 * @param {object} opts - Foos options.
 * @param {function} opts.biz - Some callback.
 */
class Foo {
    constructor(opts) {}
}
```

**Bar**

```
/**
 * This is Bar.
 *
 * @extends Foo
 */
class Bar extends Foo { }
```

I tried inheritdoc, but it didnt seem to work (or Im doing it wrong).

Comment: have you found a solution?